# Enabling two (or a fixed amount) checked in a checkbox/radio button scenario

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, radio-button

Alright, here's the case.

Imagine that there's a rectangle with 4 points on it, naming rodUpLeft, rdoUpRight, rdoDownLeft, rdoDownRight as checkbox

I want to make sure that there's exactly **TWO** checked box checked **AT ALL TIMES**

(Since it's drawing a line from the two points, so I need both points to be present at all times)

Kind of like how radio button works, except instead of just one button got checked, I want two.

So I've tweaked around and came up with a code as below

```
    If sender.name = firstChoice Then
        sender.checked = True
    ElseIf Not lastChoice = sender.name Then
        Select Case lastChoice
            Case "rdoUpRight"
                rdoUpRight.Checked = False
            Case "rdoUpLeft"
                rdoUpLeft.Checked = False
            Case "rdoDownRight"
                rdoDownRight.Checked = False
            Case "rdoDownLeft"
                rdoDownLeft.Checked = False
        End Select
        lastChoice = firstChoice
        firstChoice = sender.name
    End If
```

So my initially idea is to track the buttons that were clicked, and uncheck the old button when a new unchecked button is clicked.

However, it does not stop the user from unchecking already checked checkbox, thus breaking the rest of the code.

A help would be much appreciated.

> ### Reza Aghaei
>
> If 1, 2 are checked. then what is the result of clicking on 3?

Well, this is the case scenario

Say there's 3 button, namely btn1, btn2, btn3

Initially btn1 and btn2 are both checked, and we assign a sequence to the buttons clicked, but since this is the script's initialization, so I declared that btn1 is the first being checked, followed by btn2

> Step 1 - Initial
>
> > o btn1 - first checked (defined manually at init)
> >
> > o btn2 - last checked (defined manually at init)
> >
> > x btn3 - unchecked

Then when btn3 got checked, we want to remove the button that got checked first, in this case, btn1, and all the sequence of the checking order gets pushed up

> Step 2 - Clicked on btn3
>
> > x btn1 - got unchecked because it's the first one that got checked
> >
> > o btn2 - first checked (sequence got shift up)
> >
> > o btn3 - last checked

It's kind of the idea of push and pop a stack while limiting the stack to remain always 2 items in it.

So let's say if you clicked btn1 again next, then

> Step 3 - Clicked on btn1
>
> > o btn1 - last checked
> >
> > x btn2 - unchecked
> >
> > o btn3 - first checked (sequence got shift up)

Since we want it to act like a radio button, so that means if we tried to click on a check box that's already checked, it should remain checked, instead of unchecking it

> Step 4 - Clicked on btn1 again while it's checked
>
> > o btn1 - last checked
> >
> > x btn2 - unchecked
> >
> > o btn3 - first checked

Good, my code above works fine and all for the steps above, after all, that's the code's intention.

However, the reason of this post is when you tried to click on a check box that was checked **THE FIRST**

> Step 5 - Clicked on btn3
>
> > o btn1 - last checked
> >
> > x btn2 - unchecked
> >
> > x btn3 - unchecked **< ERROR! Shouldn't have happened**

That's the issue right here I'd like to have it fixed.

Thanks for asking for more clearification Reza

Comment: Instead of radio buttons, you can use 4 CheckBoxes also you can use 2 ComboBoxes

Comment: as stated, it's checkbox, but I want it to behave like radio button, with maximum of 2 buttons checked at all times

Comment: If 1, 2 are checked. then what is the result of clicking on 3?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've updated the post to your questions with very detailed thought approach behind it

Comment: Your question isn't totally clear to me. In your edit, you're referring to 3 buttons - do you mean checkboxes or are these actual button controls? Also you're saying 3 buttons when there are four points on the rectangle. How do the buttons relate to the points? I'm also guessing that the two checkboxes must always be at the ends of one line - not at opposite corners of the rectangle - or is this not important? If you could show all the code relating to what you're doing, this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @DavidWilson To clarify, the idea I wanted to make (in a broader sense) is to have X buttons/checkbox/radiobutton checked/lit/enabled across Y buttons/checkbox/radiobutton.

Comment: @DavidWilson In the case of wanting to try the code, go make 4 checkbox, each named rdoUpLeft, rdoUpRight, rdoDownLeft, rdoDownRight respectively. As to the code I've posted in the start, they are located in the onChange event, and you should be able to make a replica of it

Comment: The code is the same for each onchange event handler? (or one handler for all the btn/rdo/chk controls' onchance events- essentially the same thing)

Comment: Yes, same for all the event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this. On your form you have your four checkboxes named as you did in your code.

I've rewritten things a bit so that what happens is that when a box is checked, the first line in the sub creates a static list of checkboxes called **CheckBoxStack** to which we can add each checkbox when it is clicked. If you don't know about static variables, they are local variables which aren't destroyed when the sub finishes, and they retain their values when the sub runs each time after that.

The sender object is converted from an object to a checkbox and assigned to **ckBox**, the event handler for **ckBox** is disabled because whenever the **.checked** property is changed further down the code, it would fire the same sub and you could end up in an infinite loop or have an unexpected error.

Anyway, next The code has a look at the list of checkboxes in **CheckBoxStack** to see if the checkbox assigned to **ckBox** is already in there. If it is, then it sets the **.checked** property to **True**, enables the event handler again and exits the sub. This takes care of clicks on already checked boxes.

If the checkbox isn't in the list, and it has been checked, it is added to the list.

If the list contains more than 2 checkboxes, the oldest added checkbox has its event handler disabled, and is set to false before enabling its event handler again. It is then removed from the list.

Finally the handler for the clicked checkbox is enabled again.

Job Done - Does that help?

```
Private Sub CheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoUpLeft.CheckedChanged, rdoDownLeft.CheckedChanged, rdoDownRight.CheckedChanged, rdoUpRight.CheckedChanged
    Static CheckBoxStack As New List(Of CheckBox)

    Dim ckBox As New CheckBox
    If TypeOf sender Is CheckBox Then
        ckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)
    End If
    RemoveHandler ckBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBox_CheckedChanged
    With ckBox
        If CheckBoxStack.Contains(ckBox) Then
            .Checked = True
            AddHandler ckBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBox_CheckedChanged
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If .Checked = True Then
            CheckBoxStack.Add(ckBox)
            If CheckBoxStack.Count > 2 Then
                RemoveHandler CheckBoxStack.Item(0).CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBox_CheckedChanged
                CheckBoxStack.Item(0).Checked = False
                AddHandler CheckBoxStack.Item(0).CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBox_CheckedChanged
                CheckBoxStack.RemoveAt(0)
            End If
            AddHandler ckBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBox_CheckedChanged
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hm, never though about unbinding and rebinding the listeners, I'll give that a try when I'm at office. But I do have a question, is the Addhandler in line 12 necessary?

Comment: Nevermind, I see why the addhandler is needed, thanks again, it worked like a charm

Comment: Glad it works for you. One of the things I love/hate about programming is the number of different ways of solving problems.  It may be possible to write a cleverer solution using obscure code,  but I prefer code that people can come back to 6 months down the line and still figure out what it does.